# How to prevent a scrollbar with momentum scrolling from hiding itself on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, scroll, safari

When you add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to a scrollable element such as a div for instance, you gain a smoother scrolling experience (native momentum scrolling) but then, you lose the ability to have the scrollbar constantly shown. Because for some obscure reason, Apple decided it's good UX to hide the scrollbar most of the time.

The problem is that when only 3 items show in your scrollable content and the rest isn't partially cut, you have no hint telling users that there is a scrollbar and that more items are available.

Is there a way to have a scrollable div with momentum scrolling but that never hides itself?